# Specifying the font in an R console - multiplatform solutions?

Tags: r, fonts, console

This is fairly mundane as R questions go, but I would like to specify the font in my R console.  It's easy enough to do in Windows - [John Cook has an excellent little writeup](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/31/changing-the-r-console-fonts/) on that.

However, that is specific for the Windows R GUI.  I'm not able to find a way to do this (at least from within R) on RStudio, Linux, etc. Is there a global, platform-agnostic solution?  If not, what would need to be wrapped to make this feasible given per-platform idiosyncracies?

Or is this infeasible?

Note that I'm interested in the font family, rather than the font size, though font size suggestions are welcome.

Edit: I plan to apply this inside a program, if possible.  Since R can make calls to the shell, I am happy with a two-pass method that first configures external files in preparation for a subsequent invocation of R, if that is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, each of the front-ends to R are responsible for the way that the console is displayed to the user. This will be inherently platform and front-end specific.

Comment: Aargh.  Can I hope that you're wrong?  :)  If there is a standard R front-end console per platform, then presumably all isn't lost if one can identify the platform (or, even better, identify the front-end).  If so, then wrapping functionality per (platform, front-end) pair seems hypothetically feasible.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Okay, I've given up hope that you're wrong.  :)  I found some Windows and Mac solutions and nothing for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Gavin is right: this is set per frontend, and I fail to find anything for Linux.  However, the standard R frontend for Windows is addressed in my question.  Mac users may find this page helpful: [Permanently change default console font](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2010-April/007297.html).

So, the answers as I found them may be summarized as:

- Windows / default R - see John Cook's page
- Mac - see link above
- Linux / default R frontend - not possible (or am I wrong?)
- (Windows, Mac, Linux) / Rstudio - Font family is not available (yet) - see [this page](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/80-default-font).  Font size is - [this page](http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/using-rstudio/customizing-rstudio)
- Windows / Revolution R - [this page](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/faq.php?faq=winprogsettings)
- Other / Revolution R - not found

So, the universal trick is that I need to use R via a web server, and then I can configure my browser.  :)  Not going to happen.  I'll wait on Rstudio.

Comment: Link for "(Windows, Mac, Linux) / Rstudio - Font family is not available (yet) - see this page." is broken.