# Set font and font size in R Console programmatically?

Tags: windows, r, user-interface, console

Is it possible to set the [console font and font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918614/specifying-the-font-in-an-r-console-multiplatform-solutions), as I would with "Edit->GUI preferences", **programmatically**? How would a function for this look like? I am on windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows (at least), the `$R_HOME/etc/Rconsole` config file sets many optional parameters for the console and pager. Here's the section that you could hand-edit to change the default font and font size:

```
## Font.
# Please use only fixed width font.
# If font=FixedFont the system fixed font is used; in this case
# points and style are ignored. If font begins with "TT ", only
# True Type fonts are searched for.
font = TT Courier New
points = 10
style = normal # Style can be normal, bold, italic
```

To change the values from the command line of an active R session, you could use the `loadRconsole()` function. It reads in a text file containing directives of the form shown above, which will overwrite the values read from `Rconsole` when R was launched.  Here's an example:

```
temp <- tempfile()
cat("points = 13\n", file = temp)
cat("style = italic\n", file = temp, append = TRUE)
loadRconsole(file = temp)

## And then, to reset to the defaults:
loadRconsole(file = file.path(R.home(), "etc/Rconsole"))
```

Comment: Seems like `cat` is rewriting the tempfile, but with `append=TRUE` this works great. Thanks!

Comment: @KarstenW. -- Yes, thanks. I forgot to add that when I cleaned it up for presentation. (I tested it with a single-line cat call.)